# How to type database response document

Tags: typescript, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I am trying to use CouchDB, and it's `nano` npm library that has typescript types. I managed to insert documents, however I don't know how to type a response document. Here is the function that gets the data:

```
export const getAlarms = async (): Promise<IAlarm[]> => {
  const list = await db.list({ include_docs: true });
  const alarms = list.rows.map(alarm => {
    if (alarm.doc) {
      return Alarm.from(alarm.doc);}
    });
  return alarms;
};
```

Typescript throws an error at `alarm.doc`:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type 'Document' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IAlarm'.
>     Property 'name' is missing in type 'Document'.

I cannot find anywhere what to do at this point, how can I tell TS that the return document from this call is of my type and not a simple Document?

Edit: Just managed to fix it using `alarm.doc as IAlarm` - how good of an approach is it?

Comment: It's fine. Typescript debugger is there just to make your life easy. You can define alarm type wherever you want.

Comment: There may be another way to do this.  Looking at the [declarations](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano/blob/master/lib/nano.d.ts), it looks like the `use` function takes a type argument `D` for the document type and produces a `DocumentScope<D>`.  Are you getting `db` by calling `use`?  If so, call `use<IAlarm>`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen You are right, I can call `use` with the supplied type! Didn't know that this was a feature. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Where was `alarm as alarm.doc` used exactly in this example? (sorry for dredging up old qn, but there's not many with answers on this topic)